# How do I get rid of the error "struct field shorthands are unstable"?

Tags: rust

I'm trying out a Hello World application with the Iron framework. This is what I have in my main.rs:

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate router;

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;
use router::Router;

fn main() {
    let mut router = Router::new();

    router.get("/", hello_world);
    router.post("/data", randomfriend);

    fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "Hello World!")))
    }

    fn data(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "Got some data")))
    }

    Iron::new(router).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
    println!("On 3000");
}
```

Here is my Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "webserver-iron"
version = "0.1.0"

[[bin]]
name = "webapp_demo_server"

[dependencies]
iron = "*"
router = "*"
```

When I run `cargo run`, I get the following error:

```
error: struct field shorthands are unstable (see issue #37340)
```

Seems like this issue has been fixed, but how can I get rid of it? I have the following Rust version:

```
rustc 1.16.0 (30cf806ef 2017-03-10)
```

Comment: You should probably update to the latest stable compiler. Also, which line does this error trigger on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Struct field shorthands went into Rust 1.17.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/rust-1.17-relnotes/RELEASES.md#version-1170-2017-04-27) (as [RFC 1682](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1682-field-init-shorthand.md)), so you'll have to upgrade your Rust installation.

If you use Rustup, see [these instructions how to keep your Rust installation up-to-date](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs#keeping-rust-up-to-date).

Comment: Would you mind also sharing how to update it on a Mac? I installed Rust on my Mac using the rustup script!